# Rename files to their BASE64

Tags: 14.04, command-line, bash, scripts, filename

I want to rename only filenames to their BASE64, not extension. So I created this script which doesn't work. Can anyone tell its problem please?

```
#!/bin/bash
#initialize with random text
onlyfilename="abc"
extension="def"
#go through all files in the directory
for filename in ./*;
do
        #avoid my script files (enc & dec)
        if [ $filename != "./enc" ] && [ $filename != "./dec"  ]; then
                #remove ./ from beginning and get just filename
                $onlyfilename=$(basename ${filename:2})
                #get extension
                $extension=${onlyfilename##*.}
                #check if they are correct
                echo $onlyfilename
                echo $extension
                #rename filename to base64
                mv "$filename" "$(echo -n $onlyfilename | base64).$extension"
        fi
done
```

Purpose: I want to rename my files to their Base64 and download them. Will a Base64 filename will be a valid filename to download? If not, is there any alternative to Base64?

Comment: I would have asked this on SO: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37445732/bash-rename-files-to-base64-value-of-the-filenames ;)

Comment: @Rinzwind This is perfectly On-topic here. Why would OP asked this on SO?

Comment: Where did I say I considered this off topic? @heemayl  All I said is that I would have asked this on SO. Next: I did also not vote to close this :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got help from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37445732/bash-rename-files-to-base64-value-of-the-filenames).

To encode:

```
#!/bin/bash
#ENCODE
for file in *;
do
    if [ $file != "enc" ] && [ $file != "dec"  ]; then
        new_name=$(echo -n "${file%.*}" | base64 -w0)
        mv "$file" "$new_name.${file##*.}"
    fi
done
```

To decode:

```
#!/bin/bash
#DECODE
for file in *;
do
    if [ $file != "enc" ] && [ $file != "dec"  ]; then
        new_name=$(echo -n "${file%.*}" | base64 -w0 --decode)
        mv "$file" "$new_name.${file##*.}"
    fi
done
```

I tested both; they work.

Answer (score 1):

As one-liner

```
$ for file in * ; do echo  "$file" "$(basename $file | base64 )"."${file##*.}" ; done
file1.png ZmlsZTEucG5nCg==.png
file2.jpeg ZmlsZTIuanBlZwo=.jpeg
file3.txt ZmlsZTMudHh0Cg==.txt
```

Replace first `echo`  with `mv` to actually rename them

Comment: Why was my answer downvoted ? Please explain